# Date format issue while writing data-frame to excel file using xlwings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xlwings

i am trying to read a excel file and write it to another excel file using python Xlwings, but in the output1.xlsx excel file if the date value is lesser than 13 then the date and month part are getting interchanged . If the date >=13 then date value is same as input file. When i checked values in the data-frame it is correct and the issue is happening while writing the dataframe to output1.xlsx file using **Xlwings** . while using pandas.to_excel() the value are written to excel in correct format. Please help me with XLWINGS for the writing the data in dataframe to excel.

**Issue:**:

[image]

Note: in the picture left side is input data and right side is output. i have highlighted the wrong data in red color and the date values are less than 13.

**Expected output using xlwings:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlwings as xw
df=pd.concat(pd.read_excel("input.xlsx",sheet_name=None,parse_dates=False,na_filter = False,dtype=str), ignore_index=True)
app = xw.App(visible=False)
# 1st output file using xlwings --> here the date vaues are wrong in output file output1.xlsx
book = xw.Book("output1.xlsx")
sht = book.sheets("Sheet1")
sht.range('A1').options(index=False,dates=False).value=df
book.save()
book.close()
app.quit()

# 2nd output file using pandas to_excel() -->> here the date values are correct
df.to_excel("output2.xlsx",index=False)
```

**Files:**
[input files link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FM3lqc8B6hIu5WQOmQQ7qCg8o4GiLvW_/view?usp=sharing)